# Creating an interactive segue between two UIViewControllers in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, segue

I'm a bit lost on how to implement interactive transitions. After looking at a dozen tutorials, each of which is *not quite* what I want, I will ask here. Hopefully if I figure this out it can be useful to others in the future.

What I want is an interactive transition (using a swipe gesture) to transition from one UIViewController to another. The actual transition will have some cool animations.

How can I create a reusable custom & interactive segue which uses `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition`? I don't need a fully coded answer — I'm really just looking for the blueprint of what methods should be involved, and how they hook up.

If my question is unclear, I can explain more.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly was wrong with the tutorials you looked at? I mean, I could certainly show you code that does a custom interactive segue using UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, but you must already have found that and you are rejecting it, so what would be the point? What do you expect to learn here that you have not learned already?

Comment: @matt Actually I have not found one of the flavor I'm looking for. If I had more knowledge of Swift & iOS I could probably adapt one of the ones I've found, but I don't have that knowledge yet. I'm trying.

Comment: I don't know what "flavor" means. If you can't "adapt" what you can find, that suggests that what you are asking for _here_ is that someone should write the whole code for you. But that's not going to happen — nor can it, since you have not said what the animation is. Any example is going to be no more than a "blueprint" — which is just what you claim you want.

Comment: So, here's a downloadable UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition example, but I've little confidence that it will mean any more to you than what you've already found: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/3c1c280c9ad2787fc1bdb8836203a5b21fc7ea45/bk2ch06p296customAnimation2old/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.swift